# How to properly dispose multiple forms

Tags: c#

**Question**: How to properly dispose the ScreenSaverForm(s) that is created in the method `ShowScreensaver`?

When I run CODE ANALYSIS from Visual Studio it reports the following: `In method 'Program.ShowScreenSaver()', call System.IDisposable.Dispose on object 'ssf' before all references to it are out of scope`.

I don't understand how to do that because the Application enters an anonymous message loop afters exiting method `ShowScreenSaver()`. Only the screensavers themselves can stop the application by calling `Application.Exit()` on mousemove-event. **Should the screensaverForms dispose themselves perhaps?**

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
                ShowScreenSaver();
                Application.Run();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Display the form on each of the computer's monitors.
    /// </summary>
    static void ShowScreenSaver()
    {
        ScreenSaverForm ssf;
        foreach (Screen screen in Screen.AllScreens)
        {
            ssf = new ScreenSaverForm(screen.Bounds);
            ssf.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Simplified code of the Screensaver class

```
public partial class ScreenSaverForm : Form
{
    public ScreenSaverForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Display pretty image
        ShowprettyImage();
    }
    private void ScreenSaverForm_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!mouseLocation.IsEmpty)
         {
             // Terminate if mouse is moved a significant distance
             if (Math.Abs(mouseLocation.X - e.X) > 25 ||
                 Math.Abs(mouseLocation.Y - e.Y) > 25)
                 Application.Exit();
         }

         // Update current mouse location
         mouseLocation = e.Location;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To comply with code analysis, you can just do:

```
static void ShowScreenSaver() {
    foreach (Screen screen in Screen.AllScreens) {
        ScreenSaverForm form = new ScreenSaverForm(screen.Bounds);

        form.FormClosed += (sender, e) => {
            form.Dispose();
        };

        form.Show();
    }
}
```

If you know when you will be done with it and you no longer need it, get rid of it.

Comment: there is no any reason to call esplicitly Dispose, unless you do not *really* need that. If you need thats(some non managed resource cleanup, for example), it can be perfectly handled *inside* form itself.

Comment: I'm sorry your offended you lost a point for your post, but you did not answer his question at all, and moreso there are many good reasons to explicitly dispose your objects. You should read up more about how garbage collection works.

Comment: there is no reason to make it esplicit till there is some esplicit clean up to do. If you have a simple form just close it, and let GC to take care of the cleanup. If you *know* that there is something in that form that can not be cleanup automatically, implement IDisposable and inside implementation of it's method cleanup your resources. Dispose will be called by the framework or by type consumer.

Comment: I'm not going to discuss this here because there are ample topics on it and its out of scope for this topic, and "let the GC take care of it" is not a reason to disregard best practice. There's a reason this is a code analysis rule to begin with, you might want to start your research there, as well as areas like reference counting and GC cycles.

Comment: @David: Agree completely. You can get some really nasty memory leak problems if you fail to call Dispose(). This often happens when the Dispose() method unsubscribes from the event handler of an object that stays alive until the program ends. If you fail to unsubscribe your form from such an object, there will be a live reference to your form until the program ends. By not calling Dispose(), you will therefore fail to unsubscribe.

Answer (score 0):

Let them dispose themselves.  They'll be freed up when the screensaver stops and the executable is shut down.

If you really want to, you can make the ssf object a class level field and dispose of it when the application shuts down, and that would be the *best* practice.

You could also have `ShowScreenSaver` return the form, and use the `Application.Run` that takes a form as a parameter, and add an event to the application exit that will dispose of it for you.

```
ScreenSaverForm form = ShowScreenSaver();
Application.ApplicationExit += (sender, e) => form.Dispose();
Application.Run(form);
```

Answer (score -1):

First I would say bring `ssf` variable into the loop

```
static void ShowScreenSaver()
{

    foreach (Screen screen in Screen.AllScreens)
    {
        ScreenSaverForm ssf = new ScreenSaverForm(screen.Bounds);
        ssf.Show();
    }
}
```

This *may* already resolve a problem.

It's enough to manage, *if you need that*, the disposal inside the form itself.